# How can I schedule an OIC integration across varying month lengths, including handling leap years?

Tags: oracle, cloud, erp, fusion

How can I schedule an OIC integration in a year for 31 days of separate logic, 30 days of separate logic, and 28 days of separate logic?
If there is a leap year, how to schedule for the appropriate year's 29 days.

FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=1,3,5,7,8,10,12;BYMONTHDAY=16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31;BYHOUR=19;BYMINUTE=00;BYSECOND=0;&
FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=4,6,9,11;BYMONTHDAY=16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30;BYHOUR=19;BYMINUTE=00;BYSECOND=0; &
FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=2;BYMONTHDAY=16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28;BYHOUR=19;BYMINUTE=00;BYSECOND=0;